# angular ui-router refresh only one part of the page, need multiple views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an angular app where I present a navigation bar on the left with normal ui-sref's going to states like `schedules` and `clients`.  On the clients view I present a list of clients (which animates in, slides in from left).  Then I want to achieve the follow:

1. When a client is clicked on, load their information into the main part of the screen
2. Update the URL so that if they were to refresh at this point the same client would be selected
3. DO NOT re-instantiate the clients controller, as doing so re-animates the client list sliding in.

I've got #1 working, but can't get 2 or 3 to work in a way that I want.  I can get the url to update, but doing so re-instantiates the clients controller and re-animates the client list, and no amount of `{notify: false}` or any other combo of options I've tried seems to do the trick.  I did see the `$urlRouter.deferIntercept()` but I'm not sure how that applies to this situation.  Do I need multiple views to achieve this, where clicking on a client just updates the "profile" section of the page?  Thanks so much!

Comment: You should show the code you're using to set up the various states/URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by loading a particular client in a substate of `clients`, with an associated URL that identifies the client.

```
$stateProvider.state('clients', {
    url: 'clients/',
    resolve: {
        clients: function () {
            // return the clients collection or a promise which will resolve with it
        }
    }
    // template, controller, etc
});

$stateProvider.state('clients.client', {
    url: 'client/{id:[1-9][0-9]+}/', // as this is a substate, this gets appended the the parent state's URL for an end result of something like /#/clients/client/1
    resolve: {
        client: ['$stateParams', 'clients', function ($stateParams, clients) {
            // Lookup the client in clients using $stateParams.id and return it or a promise that will resolve with it
        }]
    }
    // template, controller, etc
});
```

Then put a `ui-view` in the template for the `clients` state to give the `clients.client` substate somewhere to render.

When you first load any URL that starts with `clients/` you'll enter the `clients` state. Navigation to and between substates will only run the substate transition code (resolves, controller, etc). Until you leave the `clients` parent state and return, the `clients` transition code will not run again.

The [ui.router readme](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/README.md) has good info about nesting states, and they a provide [demo app](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/) that really helped me understand the idea of a state hierarchy. That demo bears a lot of similarity to what you're building.

Comment: You sir, are the man.  Thank you for this, worked exactly how I expected it to.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, I'm happy to hear it!